# How to fire Quartz.net job running in windows service from web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net, spring.net

Quartz.net has changed and I am unable to find examples or documentation to develop a solution with Jobs scheduled in a windows service with Spring.net configuration i.e. not adding the trigger and schedule programmatically. Also want to trigger a job from a web application on demand.

Please could you provide example or documentation as to how the following can be done,
1) Creating jobs with spring.net configuration(appContext.xml)
2) Trigger on demand job(scheduled in windows service) from web application

Answer (score 0):

To perform that you need to interact with quartz job manager. You need to exchange data between Web app and Windows Services, exist many ways to do that (WCF, Web API, NancyFX apis...)

Now you can make calls to job scheduler. Basically, look spring. Net documentation to see how to interact with quartz. Make that on your api (hosted on your Windows. services). 
Does not forget about security.